# Allowing users to delete their accounts leads to 400 Bad Request in Flask

Tags: python, post, flask, delete-row, http-status-code-400

I am having problems with setting up user account deletion option. I have set up a Bootstrap modal to pop up for assurance and I want the 'Delete' button to delete the current user's account from the database, log the user out, and redirect the user to the homepage with a flash message. However, when I click the button it throws out a 400 Bad Request Error. I don't know if the reason is the POST method or something else, so here I am, asking for your help. I am using PostgreSQL along with SQLAlchemy, and Flask-Login (for the `current_user`) in my application. This is my first time setting up something like this, and if my question is not clear enough, please let me know so I can provide more details. Also if you have a suggestion on how can I optimize this, I would be more than grateful to hear it. Here is the related code:

**The button in the modal:**

```
<form action="{{ url_for('user.delete_account') }}" method="POST">
  <input type="submit" id="delete" name="delete" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger">
</form>
```

**The route and the delete function:**

```
@user.route('/delete', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def delete_account():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['delete'] == 'Delete':

            current_user.delete()

            flash('Your account has been successfully deleted.', 'success')
            return redirect(url_for('core.home'))
```

I really hope that my question is clear enough, because I got stuck with this for more than 10 hours straight and I need the help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**FOUND THE SOLUTION:**

So basically, I played around a bit with the code and found the solution. Here is the relevant code:

**First, I created a Jinja2 macro with a hidden CSRF token:**

```
{%- macro form_tag(endpoint, fid='', css_class='', method='post') -%}
  <form action="{{ url_for(endpoint, **kwargs) }}" method="{{ method }}"
        id="{{ fid }}" class="{{ css_class }}" role="form">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ caller () }}
  </form>
{%- endmacro -%}
```

**After that I created the simplest form possible:**

```
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import SubmitField


class DeleteUserForm(Form):
    delete = SubmitField('Delete')
```

**After that I added this to the Bootstrap modal:**

```
{% import 'macros/form.html' as f with context %}

{% call f.form_tag('user.delete') %}
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
{% endcall %}
```

**At last, I modified the route in my views.py file:**

```
@user.route('/settings/delete', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def delete():
    form = DeleteUserForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        current_user.delete()

        flash('Your account has been successfully deleted. Hope to see you again.', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('user.login'))

    return render_template('user/login.html', form=form)
```

This solution was the best I could do. I hope this will help someone else too. Oh, and I almost forgot, since I was editing my `settings.html` file, I also had to pass the `form=form` argument in my `/settings` route of the page:

```
@user.route('/settings')
@login_required
def settings():
    form = DeleteUserForm()
    return render_template('user/settings.html', form=form)
```

That's all. Thanks to the ones who posted an answer too, I appreciate it.

Comment: Ah, so the problem was that you had CSRF checks in your app (maybe from [Flask-WTF](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/csrf.html)?) and you weren't even getting to your handler.  Thanks for bringing the answer back.

Comment: That's true. As I am still not experienced enough, I simply forgot to implement the CSRF...for the 5th time in my app. I learned that as a general rule, POST requests require CSRF tokens to work. Never gonna forget that now haha.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: It turns out that the issue is *probably* from a globally installed CSRF protection layer (from something like [Flask-WTF](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/csrf.html)).  Debugging if you are even getting to your handler will greatly help in creating a minimal reproducible example.

---

**Original Best-Guess Answer**: You are almost certainly getting a 400 Bad Request error from `request.form['delete']` - Flask raises such an error when you attempt to get a value out of `request.{form, args, values}` that wasn't sent to the server (the error raised is also a subtype of `KeyError` which an ordinary Python dictionary would raise in the same case:

```
({ "x": 123 })["y"]  # Raises a KeyError
request.form["not-in-form"]  # Raises a BadRequest error
```

So now the question is, "why is 'delete' not in the form request?".  The answer there is almost certainly because you are catching the submit event for this form in JavaScript and submitting the form programmatically ... and not including the value of the button.  Include the necessary parameter or simply don't check for the form value (or even for the method, since you've already limited the route to only receive `POST`).

```
@user.route('/delete', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def delete_account():
    current_user.delete()

    flash('Your account has been successfully deleted.', 'success')
    return redirect(url_for('core.home'))
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but it somehow did not work for me, I was still getting errors. However, I found another solution, and I have posted it in the answers.

Comment: If there is a  KeyError, the server should return 50x.

Comment: In this case the error that `request.form['not-there'] ` throws is actually a sub-type of `BadRequest` (*and* `KeyError`) - [see the code for more details](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/778f482d1ac0c9e8e98f774d2595e9074e6984d7/werkzeug/datastructures.py#L379-L382)